# Export the data to excel sheet column wise using apache poi?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

i managed to write the data to a single column.
My req is to write the data to the next adjacent column without overriding the data in the fist column.
Any help?

```
InputStream inp;
    try {
        inp = new FileInputStream("D:\\test.xls");
        Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(inp);
        Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        Row row =  null;

        Cell c = null;

        int rowNum=0;
        Set<String> keySet = new HashSet<String>();
        keySet = tushMap.keySet();
        for (Entry<String, String> entry : tushMap.entrySet()) {
            row=sheet.createRow((short) (sheet.getLastRowNum() + 1));
            System.out.println((short) (sheet.getLastRowNum() + 1));
            c = row.createCell(0);
            c.setCellValue("fff");
            System.out.println("fff");
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "/" + entry.getValue());
            rowNum++;
        }


        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("D:\\test.xls");
        wb.write(fileOut);
        fileOut.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidFormatException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This is the code written to populate the 1st column.
Populating the second column overrides the fist 1..
Pls suggest some solution..
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the data side by side get the last row outside the loop and save it as the begening row. Keep a counter for which row you are editing inside the loop. If the row is null create the row.

```
rowPos = sheet.getLastRowNum();
for (Entry<String, String> entry : tushMap.entrySet()) {
    rowPos++;
    Row currentRow = sheet.getRow(rowPos);
    if(null == currentRow)
        currentRow = createRow(rowPos);
```

EDIT:

I am getting the desierd output using this

```
int beginingRow = sheet.getLastRowNum();
            for( int col=0; col<2; col++){
                int currentRow = beginingRow;
                for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
                    currentRow++;
                    row = sheet.getRow(currentRow);
                    if(null == row)
                        row=sheet.createRow(currentRow);
                    c = row.createCell(col);
                    c.setCellValue("fff");
                    System.out.println("fff");
                    //System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "/" + entry.getValue());
                    rowNum++;
                }
            }
```

Output

```
fff fff
fff fff
fff fff
fff fff
fff fff
fff fff
fff fff
fff fff
fff fff
fff fff
```

Comment: did that..also changed sheet.getLastRowNum() + 1 to sheet.getFirstRowNum()+1 (+1 so as to skip the column headers)